# Reseting the counter every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, countdown

Ok so I am using a [jquery countdown plugin](https://github.com/duncmc/jQuery-Countdown-Timer/blob/master/js/jquery.countdown-timer.js) and the declaration is below

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j('#clock').countdown( { to : "#{event.start_date.strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M")}", remaining : "#{event.start_date - Time.now}", display_on_complete : 'list', hide_on_complete : 'countdown' } );
});
```

this works fine but every 30 seconds i need to update this countdown with time from this ajax call

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    function refresh() {
    $j.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo&output=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
    unix_timestamp = data.Result.Timestamp
    var json_date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
    console.log(json_date);
    setTimeout(refresh, 30000);
    }
});
```

As you can see the date is json_date variable.....and i need to replace the Time.now in the countdown method every 30 seconds...any ideas on how to achieve this

Comment: I don't see you calling the refresh() function from anywhere but inside itself? I understand you want to loop it, but it doesn't look like you've initalized it.

Comment: I see no issue with your code, the only possible problem may be context.  try defining your function as `window.refresh = function () {...};` and see if things behave differently.  Also, your code is missing a set of `});`

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery-countdown-Timer plugin doesn't support setting a arbitrary remaining time.

Also, the plugin doesn't take `remaining` as an option. (Nor it has `display_on_complete` or hide_on_complete` options. If you are linking to the wrong plugin, please let me know.)

Assuming that you want the plugin to have arbitrary remaining time is your concern, you'd have to modify the plugin.

I'd change the line 42~50 of `jquery.countdown-timer.js` to:

```
if (options.remaining) {
    seconds_remaining = options.remaining;
} else {
    // Split the specified date/time string into an array
    var date_elements = options.to.split(':');

    // Create Date objects for start and end date/times
    var end_date = new Date (date_elements[0], date_elements[1] - 1, date_elements[2], date_elements[3], date_elements[4]);
    var start_date = new Date();

    // Calculate number of seconds remain until end date/time
    seconds_remaining = (end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime()) * .001;
}
```

And call the countdown function following way within your AJAX call:

```
function refresh() {
    $j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo&output=json",
        dataType: "json", // your url doesn't have a callback, no need for jsonp
        success: function(data){
            unix_timestamp = data.Result.Timestamp
            var json_date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);

            $j('#clock').countdown({ remaining: (event.start_date - json_date) * .001 });

            setTimeout(refresh, 30000);
        }
    });
}
```

This is assuming that the `event` object is within the scope of `refresh` function and `$j` is your jQuery object.

I could be totally misinterpreting your question, so let me know if I am.